# Polarity calculation in Sentiment Analysis using TextBlob

Tags: sentiment-analysis, textblob

How is the polarity of a word in a sentence calculated using PatternAnalyser of Text Blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBlob internally uses NaiveBayes classifer for sentiment analysis,
the naivebayes classifier used in turn is the one provided by NLTK.

See Textblob sentiment analyzer code [here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/90cc87ab0f9e25f37379079840ec43aba59af440/textblob/en/sentiments.py).

```
@requires_nltk_corpus
    def train(self):
        """Train the Naive Bayes classifier on the movie review corpus."""
        super(NaiveBayesAnalyzer, self).train()
        neg_ids = nltk.corpus.movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
        pos_ids = nltk.corpus.movie_reviews.fileids('pos')
        neg_feats = [(self.feature_extractor(
            nltk.corpus.movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in neg_ids]
        pos_feats = [(self.feature_extractor(
            nltk.corpus.movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in pos_ids]
        train_data = neg_feats + pos_feats

 #### THE CLASSIFIER USED IS NLTK's NAIVE BAYES #####

        self._classifier = nltk.classify.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)

    def analyze(self, text):
        """Return the sentiment as a named tuple of the form:
        ``Sentiment(classification, p_pos, p_neg)``
        """
        # Lazily train the classifier
        super(NaiveBayesAnalyzer, self).analyze(text)
        tokens = word_tokenize(text, include_punc=False)
        filtered = (t.lower() for t in tokens if len(t) >= 3)
        feats = self.feature_extractor(filtered)

        #### USE PROB_CLASSIFY method of NLTK classifer #####

        prob_dist = self._classifier.prob_classify(feats)
        return self.RETURN_TYPE(
            classification=prob_dist.max(),
            p_pos=prob_dist.prob('pos'),
            p_neg=prob_dist.prob("neg")
        )
```

Source for NLTK's NaiveBayes classifier is [here.](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html). This returns probability distribution which is used for the result returned by Textblobs sentiment analyzer.

```
def prob_classify(self, featureset):
```